# If empty cell then fill another cell by value from third cell - loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The situation:

In cells `"D18:D94"` and `"E18:94"` I have  dropdown lists (data validation). In an additional sheet `"Sheet2"` in cells `"R18:94"`, I have a formula.

Output wanted:

If cell `"E18"` is not empty then insert the value from `"Sheet2!U18"` to cell `"F18"`. I want to loop this for each row from range.

I made something like this, but I don't know how to loop.

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E18").Value <> "" Then 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F18").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("R18")
End if
```

I don't want to set formula in `Sheet1! "F"` column because I have a dynamic print area.

Comment: Do we use U or R?

Comment: Hello PT, in terms of for loop syntax you might find this useful: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html. You can loop through each cell in a Range object to check its value for example.  If you ranges are to be dynamic you can find last row by doing something similar to https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/

Comment: "R" in Sheet2. sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below sub-

```
Sub FillData()
Dim sRng As Range, Rng As Range
Set sRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E18:E94")

    For Each Rng In sRng
        If Rng.Value <> "" Then
            Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("R" & Rng.Row)
        End If
    Next Rng
    
Set sRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @PT If you found this working then please consider accepting the answer so that other visitor can understand you problem is solved. Tick mark it to accept.